# How to do Back Propagation Updation for below code?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, backpropagation, numpy

Below is the code by Siraj Raval for implementing Neural Networks from Scratch. I have some doubts regarding the Code:

1. Why during updation he did W2 = W2 + L1.T.dot(L2_Delta). I Mean shouldn't it be W2 = W2 - L1.T.dot(L2_Delta) as we should move in the opposite direction of the gradient as in Gradient Descent
2. According to the fundamental equation of Backpropagation

   [image]

The Update should be done as Shown in equation BP2 but in code, but the order is opposite in the code ??

> L1_Delta =(L2_Delta.dot(W2.T)) * Sigmoid(L1,Deriv = True)  # Hidden Layer Error

Similarly for Equation BP4 the Gradient

> W2 += L1.T.dot(L2_Delta)

I think It Should be :

> W2 += (L2_Delta).dot(L1.T)

```
# A Three Layer Model Layer 1: Input Layer
# Layer 2 = Hidden layer , Layer 3 = Output layer
#nO.OF wEIGHTS = #lAYERS - 1
import numpy as np

def Sigmoid(Z,Deriv = False):
    P = np.reciprocal(1+np.exp(-Z))
    if Deriv == False:
        return P
    else:
        return Z*(1-Z)

#Input Data
X = np.array([[0,0,1],[0,1,1],[1,0,1],[1,1,1]])
Y = np.array([[0],
              [1],
              [1],
              [0]])

np.random.seed(1)
W1 = 2*np.random.random((3,4)) - 1
W2 = 2*np.random.random((4,1)) - 1

#Training

for j in range(60000):
    L0 = X  #Input Layer
    L1 = Sigmoid(np.dot(L0,W1))  #First Hidden Layer
    L2 = Sigmoid(np.dot(L1,W2))  # Output Layer

    L2_Error = Y - L2

    if j % 1000 == 0:
        print("Error: " + str(np.mean(np.abs(L2_Error))))

    L2_Delta = L2_Error * Sigmoid(L2,Deriv = True)   #Output Layer Error
    #Now How much layer 1 contributed in the error of Layer 2
    L1_Error = L2_Delta.dot(W2.T)
    L1_Delta = L1_Error * Sigmoid(L1,Deriv = True)  # Hidden Layer Erro

    #Updates
    W2 += L1.T.dot(L2_Delta)
    W1 += L0.T.dot(L1_Delta)
print("Output After Training")
print(L2)
```